# How to search through a custom structure list (C#) containing a string and byte?

Tags: c#, list, byte

I am trying to search through a list that contains a structure:

```
struct Item
{
    public string Name;
    public Byte[] Data;
}
static List<Item> Items = new List<item>();
```

Each time I receive the data, bytes change and have to be updated. Is there a way to search for the item that has to be updated, without for each loop?

Also, database is too slow for this - it has to happen in memory (list shouldn't exceed 1MiB)

Thanks

Comment: Would it be acceptable to use a `Dictionary<string, Byte[]>` instead of the struct + list? Then lookups would be `O(1)`.

Comment: If declired like this:
Dictionary<string, Byte[]> Items = new Dictionary<string, Byte[]>();
should it be possible to update items like this?
Items["uniquecode"] = newBytes;
?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If the key doesn't exist, a new entry is created with the specified value, and if the key already exists the existing value is updated with the new one. It's very fast.

Comment: Tested- excellent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with dictionary, as suggested by Matthew Watson in the first reply.

```
static Dictionary<string, Byte[]> Items = new Dictionary<string, Byte[]>();
```

And updating the list with

```
Items[currentItem] = GetByteFromData(data);
//and
Items.Remove(currentItem);
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Linq?

var targetItem = items.First ( x => x.Name == targetValue);

Not sure it is faster than a foreach though.
Might be of interest that, unless it has changed recently, for loops are faster than foreach loops.

Comment: FirstOrDefault should be the choice here in case there is no targetValue. In any case the foreach is just hidden and executed inside the Linq code. For performances it is better to change the storage to a Dictionary

Comment: Yes the dictionary is better - I wrote this before I saw that suggestion.